# LAN with AD server: recurring slow link problems, how to diagnose?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a multi-site Active Directory domain.  All domain controllers across all sites are running Windows 2012 Standard R2.

Site 1 and 2: everything works fine

Site 3: I just setup and I’m having consistent problems across various computers where

1. First login to a computer sometimes takes a long time (initial account setup of a domain user on a new computer)
2. Group policy mapped drives do not appear, even though gpresult reports that the group policy was correctly applied
3. `gpupdate` will often take a long time to apply.

I have confirmed that the sites are setup correctly in AD, and that only the two local AD servers are attached to the local site.  Furthermore, I have confirmed via `echo %logonserver%` that my local machines are only using the local AD servers to login.

I can ping the AD servers consistently with <1ms response time.  All network cable in the building is recently installed and CAT6, and the symptoms do not seem to consistently affect one computer above the others: it is quite random.  Sometimes mapped drives load successfully, sometimes not.  There are only about 15 computers in the building, and all pass through a 48-port gigabit Cisco switch which is running the latest firmware available.

The AD servers themselves are running on a VM atop an Intel i5, RAID SSDs, and each have 8GB of memory apportioned.

The only common clue I see when running `gpresult` is that I am getting a `slow link detected` warning, which seems silly considering everything is on the LAN and connected via gigabit.  In my research it seems that it is to be expected that mapped drives will not reliable appear under slow link connections.

How can I go about diagnosing the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you map via unc share or dfs share name ?

Comment: The drives exist on a Synology server and I am mapping via share name like `\\synology-server\shared-folder`.  I don’t think that has anything to do with the issue though.  I’m using the exact same configuration at two other sites with absolutely no problems and quick load times.  There is a more basic network-level problem here causing the network PCs to detect a “slow-link” on a LAN connection.

Comment: Do you have subnets associated with your sites? What are the clients using for DNS, the local DC's? What do the site specific nodes in your DNS zone look like, are the appropriate DC's listed ion the appropriate nodes? Where does the Synology server live?

Comment: Yes, each site has its own subnet, and those subnets are defined in the AD Sites and Services module.  The Synology server also exists physically at the same site and the same LAN.  LAN clients in Site 3 are using the two local AD servers in Site 3 for DNS.  Within the DNS folder for Site 3 exist only definitions for the two local AD servers.

Comment: OK, as for point number 1, that's normal behavior. When a computer is first joined to the domain it doesn't yet know it's site, so it will connect to whatever DC is returned from the DNS lookup. As for point number 2; Do the users in question have the appropriate Share and NTFS permissions on the shared folders? As for point number 3; I'll have to think about the problem some more.

Comment: Point 1. I’m not talking about when first joining a PC to the domain, but about the first time a user logs into a specific computer that is *already* joined to the domain.  Point 2.  Yes, users have the correct permissions, or else drives would never map, and `gpresult` would return an error.  Currently, `gpresult` always reports successful application of policy, but the drives don’t always appear - probably 30% of the time.

I’m certain that the most important symptom here is the `slow link`, as mapped drives are not applied when there is a slow link. Why am I getting slow link over gigabit?

Comment: What's the virtualization platform?  Have you done perf testing on the site 3 AD VMs?  I've seen stuff like this when there are issues in the hypervisor, usually when memory is oversubscribed, or not enough NICs are in the box.

Comment: I have not.  Platform is VMWare ESXi 6.0.  Currently, I am running 2 VMs on one machine and 3 VMs on the other machine.  Both machines are identical with an Core i5 processor, 16GB of RAM and SSD RAID and 5 Intel Gigabit interfaces.  Both machines have 8GB for the Windows Server 2012 R2 instance.  The other VMs are linux distros with 3GB RAM each.  What tests would you recommend I perform?

Comment: @joeqwerty Here is an older link from Microsoft explaining how some policies are not applied over a slow link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/227369

Comment: gpresults doesn't report a successful drive mapping. gpresults reports the successful application of group policy. it's perfectly possible for a group policy to be applied and yet have the actual drive mapping from that group policy fail.

Comment: I understand slow link detection. Are you able to run a network capture on your switch to capture traffic from a switch port that one of the suspect computers is connected to in order to analyze the traffic to see what DC the client is communicating with?

Comment: Getting off topic here, but if I create a drive map to a shared folder that I have no permissions to, then `gpresult` will generally respond with an error of `0x80070005` which indicates Access Denied.  That is neither here nor there, however, as I have indicated that 60%+ of the time, the drive map shows up correctly and the user has full access to the folder, and all child files and folders.  This would not be possible if the permissions were incorrect.

Comment: Yes @joeqwerty.  I am running a Cisco managed switch at this site.  I will try doing that and report back.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad to help. Looking forward to seeing your findings.

Comment: Haven’t run the test yet, but I did make a new discovery.  Posted below.

Answer (score 1):

LogonServer or even nltest /dsgetdc may not accurately reflect which domain controller is used for pulling group policies.  I've seen scenarios where the local domain controller is correctly being used for authentication, but a domain controller in another site for group policies.

You need to perform:

- a netmon packet capture of the slow logon on an affected workstation.
- confirm that nltest /dsgetdc: is using the correct domain controller *and* correct IP address (if multi-homed - hopefully not).
- enable group policy environment debug logging on the affected workstation and review the logs per: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4506.group-policy-debug-log-settings.aspx

Enabling UserEnv Logging in Windows 7

In Windows 7 GPO processing is performed by a service called "Group Policy Client" .
A log file can be written by the service when implementing the following registry value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Diagnostics]  
"GPSvcDebugLevel"=dword:00030002
```

The resulting log file will be
%WINDIR%\debug\usermode\gpsvc.log

Comment: I’m running all Windows 10.  Does the Windows 7 stuff still apply?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 and later.

Comment: I'm just focusing on the failure of drive mapping now, as the slow login issue has been resolved and is apparently unrelated?  nltest /dsgetdc is showing the correct DC and IP.  I enabled GP environment debug logging, but I get inconsistent and unclear results.  I also have a netmon capture of a login with a failure to show drive maps, but it is **so much** information, I have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: Here are some errors and warnings relating to drive maps that have shown up in the gpsvc.log:  `GPSVC(158.33c) 23:33:24:921 CheckGPOs: No GPO changes but extension Group Policy Drive Maps's returned error status 183 earlier.` `GPSVC(158.c24) 23:38:12:203 ProcessGPOs(Machine): Extension Group Policy Drive Maps skipped with flags 0x110057.` `GPSVC(158.157c) 23:08:08:216 ProcessGPOs(User): Extension Group Policy Drive Maps ProcessGroupPolicy failed, status 0xb7.` But the weird thing is those errors are not consistent.  I just logged in again, no drive maps appeared, and *NO ERRORS* in the log. :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, I decided to try something...  Reset my Cisco Switch to factory defaults and the slow link problem went away.  Just to be safe, I then decided to swap out the entire switch with an identical backup Switch that I have on-site, also running factory defaults.  `gpresult` now identifies the link as high speed.  However, I am still experiencing problems where `gpupdate` takes way to long to apply (sometimes 10 seconds, sometimes 120 seconds), and also my drive map only intermittently show up.

I’m thinking maybe I should repost with a different title since the `slow link` symptom doesn’t seem to be as critical as I thought.